# URL Decode in java is not giving the same result to URL Decode php

Tags: java, php, jakarta-ee

I have made simple encryption/decryption method in php that I'm trying to move to Java

In my code, I get the value from url and urldecode it before passing it to my decryption function

This is giving right results in php but not in java

here is my test sample in php

```
urldecode("%9A%DC%CD%E1%DA%E2%D4%EA%C4%E6%9C%DA%D5%AD%CD%DF%E3%E4%C6%DB%A3%95%C4%DC%D2")
```

here is what I'm trying to do in JAVA

```
java.net.URLDecoder.decode("%9A%DC%CD%E1%DA%E2%D4%EA%C4%E6%9C%DA%D5%AD%CD%DF%E3%E4%C6%DB%A3%95%C4%DC%D2")
```

and the results I'm getting are totally different. anyone can lead me to where I messed up?

thanks

---

Comment: Maybe the java decoder can recieve a property specifing some sort of format? check the methods of that class

Comment: Lamis please post 2 different result which you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your are using only

decode(String s)

which is deprecated, the resulting string may vary depending on the platform's default encoding. Instead, use the

decode(String s,String enc)

method to specify the encoding. It decodes a application/x-www-form-urlencoded string using a specific encoding scheme.

enc can be "UTF-8", "ISO 8859-1" etc....

Comment: Yes just figured that out...decoding with ISO-885901 worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider trying instead:

```
java.net.URLDecoder.decode("%9A%DC%CD%E1%DA%E2%D4%EA%C4%E6%9C%DA%D5%AD%CD%DF%E3%E4%C6%DB%A3%95%C4%DC%D2", "UTF-8")
```

in JAVA `java.net.URLDecoder.decode(String)` is deprecated.

Comment: the problem is not with php, the problem is with java ...because I'm getting the result I want in php

Comment: maybe would be good to add the result you are getting from each laguage ;)

Comment: As far as we can see on documentation: *The resulting string may vary depending on the platform's default encoding. Instead, use the decode(String,String) method to specify the encoding.* (this could be happening with you)

Comment: @Lamis: have you checked the end of Spaeth's line of code? The key portion is end part: `, "UTF-8")`. This may make a difference for you (or may not as I'm no pro at this sort of stuff). 1+ to Spaeth's answer.